# Moq - Need mocked function to return value passed in

Tags: mocking, moq

I have a mock that i have setup like this.  I need to return the same value that was passed in to `.CreatePersonName`

```
mock.Setup(m => m.CreatePersonName(It.IsAny<PersonName>()))
            .Returns(// what do i put here?);
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
mock.Setup(m => m.CreatePersonName(It.IsAny<PersonName>()))
            .Returns((PersonName p) => p);
```

Based on:

```
// access invocation arguments when returning a value
mock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns((string s) => s.ToLower());
```

from https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: Code now migrated to github: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart